# Delete part of string in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

If pandas df looks like that:

```
Id    Name        Gene
1    ARR_R         C
1    AR2           C
1    A3412d_R      C
1    Asfsvv        C
1    A_RUUYR_R     C
```

And I need to delete for example _R but only if it occurs in for example 5 last chars.

I tried this way:

```
df['Name']=(df.Name.replace({'_R':''}, regex=True))
```

But in this example code change `A_RUUYR_R` to 'AUUYR' and should be `A_RUUYR`. It's possible to command replace function to start from the end?

Comment: post your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use slicing and concatenation like:

```
df.Name.str[:-5] + df.Name.str[-5:].replace({'_R':''}, regex=True)
```

[out]

```
0        ARR
1        AR2
2     A3412d
3     Asfsvv
4    A_RUUYR
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: does OP wants to remove _R for 0 element.? `I need to delete for example _R but only if it occurs in for example 5 last chars.`

Comment: this solution works well if all the stringe have 5 string min length, a string like `AB_R` would be changed though

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df.Name.apply(lambda x: re.sub('(?<=\w{5})_R','',x) if re.findall('\w{5}_R',x) else x)
```

Output

```
0      ARR_R
1        AR2
2     A3412d
3     Asfsvv
4    A_RUUYR
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace `_R` **if and only if** it occurs after first 5 characters, use:

```
df['Name'].str.replace('(?<=.{5})(_R)','', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0      ARR_R
1        AR2
2     A3412d
3     Asfsvv
4    A_RUUYR
Name: Name, dtype: object
```